# In joomla, how can I place module positions within a category view override?

Tags: php, joomla

I'm creating an override for the category blog view and I would like to have a module position within this layout. So, is it possible to place

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="modName" style="none" />
```

in templates/template/html/com_content/category/blog.php or do I need different code?

Comment: which version of joomla?

Answer (score 9):

Use:

```
<?php
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$renderer = $document->loadRenderer('modules');
$position = "YOURPOSITIONNAME";
$options = array('style' => 'raw');
echo $renderer->render($position, $options, null);
?>
```

Source: http://www.jeepstone.co.uk/2012/07/26/load-module-position-in-template-override-in-joomla-2-5/

The article writes about Joomla 2.5 but I've tested it in article view override of Joomla! 3.3.6 and it works too.

Answer (score 1):

The jdoc:include tag doesn't work in your overrides. What you need is the following code (replacing MODULEPOSITION with the name of the position).

```
<?php
jimport('joomla.application.module.helper');
$modules = JModuleHelper::getModules('MODULEPOSITION'); 
foreach($modules as $module) {
    echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($module);
} 
?>
```

To publish a module to the position you can just freehand type it into the position field and hit enter, you don't need to specify it in the XML file.